# What is the meaning of throttle_time_in_millis Elasticsearch stats?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I created an index in a 4 nodes Elasticsearch cluster. I added about 3.5 M documents using the java Elasticsearch API.
When asking for the stats i get a very high number in throttle_time_in_millis as follows:

```
{
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "_all": {
      "primaries": {
         "docs": {
            "count": 3855540,
            "deleted": 0
         },
         "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 1203074796,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 980255
         },
         "indexing": {
            "index_total": 3855540,
            "index_time_in_millis": 426300,
            "index_current": 0,
            "delete_total": 0,
            "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
            "delete_current": 0
         },
```

1. What is the meaning of throttle_time_in_millis?
2. What could be the reason for this to increase?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this but looking at the Java source code available [here](http://search-lucene.com/c/ElasticSearch%3arc/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/store/StoreStats.java%7C%7Cthrottle_time_in_millis) and the description of Store stats available [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html) I think this is a measure of total time taken to merge the segments. It could be an indication of poor disk I/O. an increase in throttle_time_in_millis would mean the disk is failing, but only if you have previous benchmarks that show it used to be quicker. If this figure is consistently this high then I would argue it's just a symptom of the disk type you're using or the number of documents you are storing. If you're using a traditional HDD could you try a switch to an SSD?

Comment: I gathered the disk utilization and it shows very low utilization and low disk latency so i don't think it's related to disk at this point.

Comment: I looked also at that code it was difficult to me to understand when that KPI is actually increased/decreased