# How to calculate Indexing rate?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to calculate `es`'s indexing rate myself. In `stats` api,there is a `index_time_in_millis` field,what's the meaning of the field?

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165789/what-is-the-meaning-of-throttle-time-in-millis-elasticsearch-stats

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  I believe you can calculate the index rate by doing the following:

1. Sample the index_total and index_time_in_millis for a couple time periods.
2. Subtract the index_total (sample period + 1) from index_total for the original sample period.
3. Subtract the index_time_in_millis (sample period +1) from the index_time_in_millis for the original sample period.  Then divide this number by 1000 to get seconds.
4. Finally take the number from step 2 and divide by step 3.  This will give you the number of documents indexed/sec.

Formula:  (Tindex_+1 - Tindex)/((Indx_time_milis_+1 - Indx_time_milli)/1000)

Comment: Testing this method and comparing to the monitoring screen in Kibana with x-pack does not show the same result